# Javascript RegExp for a long sentence

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove system information when I use getPlainBody() functions in emails.

I tried to write a regexp, but this one seems too hard for me:

> System info: Mi A1,
>   androidOS(v7.99.2)(android)(3593)(rev.136)(cbf87b2346eabe6ef)(6c72426bbc-151c-449c-a33d-3733234d404f)(SomeuserName23542)

I tried to `.replace(/System+[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi,'')`
But it gives an error, I also tried playing around first and last part, but it seems I just don't quite understand the rules.

Comment: What exactly is your desired output? Your current regex has an unmatched `)` at the end, which is why the error is appearing

Comment: which part do you want removed?  can you provide a few more examples to make sure a solution works on each type of string you encounter

Comment: Why do you have `m+` in the regexp? Do you really want to match `Systemmmmmmmm`?

Comment: You don't match any of the spaces after `System`.

Comment: `)` is a special character in regexp. If you want to match `)` literally, you need to escape it as `\)`.

Comment: my desired output was to replace all technical info with a whitespace. I explained it further in the comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Since you've stated that you need to eliminate any lines that start with `System info:` and end with 7 groups of parenthesized strings, this should work for you:

```
.replace(/^(?:System info:)(?:[^(]+(?=\())?(?:\([^)]+\)){0,7}$/gim, '');
```

That pattern will match *up to* 7 groups of parenthesized strings (I wasn't sure if you would always have exactly 7 groups, so I treated that as an upper limit).

Breaking that pattern down:

```
^                   // start of line (multiline mode)
(?:                 // start non-capturing group
    System info:    // exactly match the literal text "System info:"
)                   // end non-capturing group
(?:                 // start non-capturing group
    [^(]            // match anything that is not a literal "("
    +               //      at least once, and as many times as possible
    (?=             // start positive lookahead group
        \(          // match a literal "("
    )               // end positive lookahead group
)                   // end non-capturing group
?                   // make it optional
(?:                 // start non-capturing group
    \(              // match a literal "("
    [^)]+           // match anything that is not a literal ")"
    \)              // match a literal ")"
)                   // end non-capturing group
{0,7}               // between exactly 0 and 7 times.
$                   // end of line (multiline mode)
```

[You can test strings against the match here.](https://regex101.com/r/mgWw3p/5)

For the record, a `+` tells the RegEx engine to match whatever precedes it at least once and as many times as possible, *greedily* (meaning the engine will only give back characters if it absolutely has to in order to make an overall match).

**Original**

Without knowing more about your desired output, my best guess as to what you're looking for is this (which probably requires a little explanation):

```
.replace(/^System info:[\w\d\s(),._-]+$/gim, '');
```

Breaking that down...

```
^                   // start of line (in multiline mode)
System info:        // exactly match the literal string "System info:"
[\w\d\s(),._-]+     // match any amount of characters that are either:
                    //      "A" through "Z",
                    //      or "a" through "z",
                    //      or "0" through "9",
                    //      or are whitespace,
                    //      or a literal "(",
                    //      or a literal ")",
                    //      or a literal ",",
                    //      or a literal ".",
                    //      or a literal "_",
                    //      or a literal "-",
$                   // end of line (in multiline mode)
```

[You can test it here](https://regex101.com/r/mgWw3p/4). Also, note the `m` flag on the regex replace which turns on multiline mode and allows `^` to match at the start of each line instead of the start of the whole string and allows `$` to match at the end of each line instead of the end of the whole string.

Unless... you wanted to capture the information (which makes the regex more complex):

```
^(System(?:\s+)?info):(?:(?:(?:\s+)?((?:[\w\d._-]+)?(?:(?:\([\w\d.-]+\))+)?)?,?))+$
```

and, of course, breaking that down...

```
^                       // start of line (in multiline mode)
(                       // start of first capture group
    System              // exactly match the string "System"
    (?:                 // start a non-capturing group
        \s+             // match any amount of whitespace
    )?                  // end non-capturing group and make the whole thing optional
    info                // exactly match the string "info"
)                       // end of first capture group
:                       // exactly match the string ":"
(?:                     // start a non-capturing group
    \s+                 // match any amount of whitespace
)?                      // end non-capturing group and make the whole thing optional
(                       // start of second capture group
    (?:                 // start a non-capturing group
        [\w\d._-]+      // match any amount of characters that are either:
                        //      "A" through "Z",
                        //      or "a" through "z",
                        //      or "0" through "9",
                        //      or a literal ".",
                        //      or a literal "_",
                        //      or a literal "-",
    )?                  // end non-capturing group and make the whole thing optional
    (?:                 // start a non-capturing group
        (?:             // start a non-capturing group
            \(          // exactly match a literal "("
            [\w\d.-]+   // match any amount of characters that are either:
                        //      "A" through "Z",
                        //      or "a" through "z",
                        //      or "0" through "9",
                        //      or a literal ".",
                        //      or a literal "_",
                        //      or a literal "-",
            \)          // exactly match a literal ")"
        )+              // end non-capturing group and make the whole thing required
    )?                  // end non-capturing group and make the whole thing optional
    ,?                  // exactly match a literal "," and make it optional
)+                      // end second capture group and make the whole thing required
$                       // end of line (in multiline mode)
```

[You can test it here](https://regex101.com/r/mgWw3p/3)

Another good resource for learning more about Regular Expressions is https://www.regular-expressions.info/ (although I don't believe there are any built-in sandboxes there, like there are at https://regex101.com).

Finally, as rightly pointed out by both [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) and [CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance) in the comments, your attempted solution of `.replace(/System+[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi,'')` will not work for two reasons:

1. the ending `)` is not marked as a literal character (i.e., `\)` or `[)]` and doesn't match a starting non-literal `(` anywhere, which will cause an error.
2. the `+` after the `m` in `System` will not match the whitespace that follows `System`, but will match `System`, or the literal `Syste` followed by any number of `m`s (e.g., `Systemmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm`).

Comment: Hi Pete, pretty impressive explanation, I thought '+' is used to combine stuff, e.g. A + B, but from your answer I understand that it multiplies the character or [] before it. I also wanted to mark the end of the line. Let me explain. 
The email might contain: user input above this technical info and also below it. I want to parse only user input, so I want to replace entire block with technical info. Thus I need to make a regexp which will start with System Info: and end with 7th ')'. There are 7 of (variables) in this block.

Comment: Here is the other example text to replace - System info: variable (variable 1)(variable 2)(variable 3)(variable 4)(variable 5)(variable 6)(variable 7). So I wanted to replace everything with a whitespace, starting from System info and ending in ')' after 7th variable in ().

Comment: that's awesome help really with all the explanations you gave. However, some lines are still coming through. E.g.
`System info: SM-G935T, androidOS(v8.0.0)(android)(3394)(rev.136)(37e843521cccc24443)(411131172415c8c)(DS)`
I think this is because of the emojis in the name.

Comment: also it doesn't catch the spaces between System info: and first (). Thanks for the link to regex101.com, really helpful site.